# How to color places with single dots in area chart - highcharts?

Tags: highcharts, area-chart

I made an area chart as in the example below:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
title: {
    text: ''
},

plotOptions: {
    series: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
    }
},

series: [{
    data: [29.9, null, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, null, 194.1, null, 54.4],
    type: 'area',
   }]
});
```

Since my second value in a series is null, I see the first value as a dot. The same happens with the values in the end of the series. Is it possible to connect it to X axis with a line which will be colored as an area of the rest of the chart?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `series.connectNulls` as a true to achieve it.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7qrtos3m/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.area.connectNulls

Comment: thanks for the answer but that is not what I would like to do. I still want to have blank space in the null areas, but I am trying to visualize the first value (29.9 in my case) and to represent it as a line which connects it to X axis.

Comment: @Felicity so maybe you can use the lollipop series for those points? https://www.highcharts.com/demo/lollipop